# centering in a table and avoiding of gaps

Tags: tables

I have the following document with a table. There are two things that are not like I want them to be. First I want the text in the fourth column to be in central position (like in the first three columns). I have to use a p-Line for this column because I want to break the line.

Moreover in the third and fourth row and fourth column there is a fairly big gap between the word "unterbrechbar" and "und". How can I avoid such a gap?

```
 \listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|p{4cm}|}
\hline
  & Szenario 1.1 & Szenario 1.2 & Szenario 1.3\\
\hline
 Waschmaschine & einmalig startbar & einmalig startbar & einmalig startbar und lastflexibel  \\
\hline 
 Trockner & einmalig startbar & unterbrechbar & unterbrechbar und lastflexibel \\
\hline 
 Geschirrspülmaschine & einmalig startbar & unterbrechbar & unterbrechbar und lastflexibel\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Load `array` package and use

```
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
```

Code:

```
 \listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}|}
\hline
  & Szenario 1.1 & Szenario 1.2 & Szenario 1.3\\
\hline
 Waschmaschine & einmalig startbar & einmalig startbar & einmalig startbar und lastflexibel  \\
\hline
 Trockner & einmalig startbar & unterbrechbar & unterbrechbar und lastflexibel \\
\hline
 Geschirrspülmaschine & einmalig startbar & unterbrechbar & unterbrechbar und lastflexibel\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To align them vertically at the center use `m` column type:

```
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}
```

as in

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}|}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you help. Now the entries are horizontally cetral but not vertically. Is there a way to make the entries vertically central (For example the entries for "einmalig startbar" should be in the middle of the cell instead of being at the upper rim)

Comment: @Felix See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

For vertical centering instead `p{<width>}` use `m{<width<}`:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
    %\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}|}
\hline
  & Szenario 1.1 & Szenario 1.2 & Szenario 1.3\\
\hline
 Waschmaschine & einmalig startbar & einmalig startbar & einmalig startbar und lastflexibel  \\
\hline
 Trockner & einmalig startbar & unterbrechbar & unterbrechbar und lastflexibel \\
\hline
 Geschirrspülmaschine & einmalig startbar & unterbrechbar & unterbrechbar und lastflexibel\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

With this you obtain table with following look-up:

[image]

Is this what you looking for?